# Calculate with literals that are out of range

Tags: java

I would like to calculate (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`) with large integers, say 50-digits long.
How can I deal with this, when `int`, `double` or `long` comes too short?

Comment: Use `java.math.BigInteger` and `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use either BigDecimal or BigInteger.  e.g.

```
BigDecimal bigno = BigDecimal(300).pow(121);
System.out.println(bigno);
```

Gives you: 539103089974329363123953948852881511919442688261355331920300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).